# What is the name of month 0?

Tags: mysql, datetime

MySQL permits you to store a `zero` value of `'0000-00-00'` as a “dummy date.”: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

I'm currently inserting into this field using `STR_TO_DATE(?, "%M %e, %Y %l:%i:%s %p")` where ? could be `June 5, 2019 5:14:47 PM`, for example.

What string can I pass to this `STR_TO_DATE` to get it to store `zero`?

Comment: Column has no default, but is nullable.  Used to be either the date didn't exist (null) or it was known.  Now I need a third option: date exists, but is unknown.  "Zero" would be perfect for this (because I check this field against null all over the place), but I can't figure out what string to pass my STR_TO_DATE to get "zero".

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Due to having to change the server mode, NO_ZERO_DATE being depreciated, and "A nondate value of 0000-00-00 is just a dumb old decision.", I'm just going to use 2000-01-01 as a dummy date.

Comment: This column records when an event happened and will never be prior to 2015.  Using a "super-future" date would create a problem when the super-future arrives.